# Execute application on shared folder using resource of shared machine

Tags: c#, oracle, winforms, server, shared-hosting

I write small apps to help automate daily work of some colleagues and want to put on a shared folder on my machine so that others from local network can execute when my computer is on. I don't have the luxury of my own server so this is the best I can do.

One of which is a Winform app that connects to an Oracle database via an Oracle client and Oracle Data Access installed on MY machine to retrieve information. I would hope that people can execute the app (.exe file) when my machine is on, without installing anything on their machine. The app will write to an output file (.html) on the same folder and open it on THEIR browser.

My question is : What should I do to make it possible ? How can people run this .exe file using Oracle Client, Oracle DataAccess and .Net framework already installed on MY machine as if I am running it locally.

I mark all C# Assemblies (automatically added by Visual Studio) as Copy Local to True (Microsoft.CSharp.dll, System.Data.dll, System.dll, System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll, System.Deployment.dll,  System.Drawing.dll, System.Net.Http.dll, System.Windows.Forms.dll, System.Xml.dll, System.Xml.Linq.dll). Would people still need .Net framework installed ? My app is quite simple with only one external dll Oracle.DataAccess.dll. How about Oracle client and Oracle Data Access.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution for your situation is create a [`webservice`](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/00a8b7/web-service/) and make the clients that'll consume your [`webservice`](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/00a8b7/web-service/) *instead* of them making direct calls to your database. It removes system dependencies and easier maintenance.

Comment: Wouldn't an ASP Web Form App work as well? Assuming you can compose a web page to do what your clients need.

Comment: Thanks Singh. My applications tend to be Windows app, with simple file output, not a website. I am not looking to build complicated enterprise app, just minimalistic app used by a handful of ppl to automate their daily tasks. Think of VBA form or app. In this case I happen to output to something in .html form

Answer (score 1):

Your colleagues can go to your computer via remote desktop if it is feasible. In the probable case that this is not feasible, you need to decide what the colleagues will see. If they only need to see the generated html and they only need to trigger the execution of your exe, then you will need to have a program which listens to a port and make sure that the given port is requested correctly by your colleagues via a small client app.

But honestly, the use-case you describe sounds like a website used by your colleagues. You can create a website in .NET, the exe you have would be the controller or code-behind depending on the approach you use and the HTML would be the response. Then the colleagues will just request your page with the port you are listening at.

Comment: Some precision : It's a single file/single form not so complicated project, just that i use connection to Oracle source. My purpose is not to write flashy, but only minimalistic programs that automate stuffs. I am a bit used to Winform so I create this app in C#, write to a text file in form of HTML (not so complicated either, just a bit of javascript to display on Google map). If I can keep in as Winform it would be great because further applications I intend to write in C#/Winform as well.

Comment: @Kenny, in that case a small command-line application would help you which would listen to requests. But honestly I think you will reach to the conclusion that a minimalistic website is needed where users could choose what should be executed. It will be easier than all the technical difficulties you will have in using your application as a website, implementing a lot of things you would get for free otherwise.

Comment: My application is not supposed to be a website. My future applications will mostly not be a website either. They would be desktop application  with a simplistic UI. You can think about VBA form, something as minimalistic as that. Let's forget the "website" part; my app will output to a text file in the same folder as the .exe. In this case the output file happens to be in .html form. In most of the other case, it would be just text file. I would like to emphasize that each app serves only handful of ppl, for repetitive tasks that otherwise take 2-3 hours. Not meant to be an enterprise app.